# How to use the output of one select statement in another Select statement?

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables

`wp_divisions` (id, div_id{fk}, player_id{fk}, div_name)

`wp_players` (id{pk}, player, cell, email).

```
wp_divisions:
1,1001,23, 3.5 Singles
2,1001,34, 3.5 Singles
3,1001,43, 3.5 Singles
4,1003,54, 4.5 Singles
5,1003,56, 4.5 Singles

wp_players:
23, Eric Simmons, 2135551234, eric@gmail.com
34, Michael Bass, 2134534321, mike@gmail.com
43, Jeff Bowman, 2134542324, jeff@gmail.com
54, Peter Pumpkin, 2137893434, pete@gmail.com
56, Jeremy Smith, 2138983465, jeremy@gmail.com
```

Jeremy logs into the website and should only see players associated with his div_id listed in a table.

I can run

```
SELECT * FROM wp_div d WHERE d.div_id = 1001;
```

I get:

```
4,1003,54, 4.5 Singles
5,1003,56, 4.5 Singles
```

My problem is I am only starting with current logged in user #56, not the div_id.

I need help with a Select Query that will get me this:

```
Peter Pumpkin, 2137893434, pete@gmail.com
Jeremy Smith, 2138983465, jeremy@gmail.com
```

using only the `wp_player.id`

I have tried this:

```
SELECT p.player, p.cell, p.email 
FROM wp_div d
INNER JOIN wp_play p ON p.id = d.player_id
WHERE d.player_id = $user_id
```

Only gives me the one line of information

```
SELECT p.player, p.cell, p.email 
FROM wp_div d
INNER JOIN wp_play p ON p.id = d.player_id
WHERE d.player_id = 54
```

I found if I use this code:

```
SELECT UPPER(`div_id`), `id`
FROM `wp_div`
WHERE `player_id` = '54'
```

I can get the `wp_div.div_id`, but I don't know how to use this output to run the next query to get my desired output:

```
Peter Pumpkin, 2137893434, pete@gmail.com
Jeremy Smith, 2138983465, jeremy@gmail.com
```

My expected results should be with using the user's id, I can get the name, cell and email address of all players in his division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a self-join between `wp_divisions`. One is to get Jeremy's row, the other is to get all the other rows in the same division.

```
SELECT p.player, p.cell, p.email
FROM wp_players AS p
JOIN wp_divisions AS d1 ON d1.player_id = p.id
JOIN wp_divisions AS d2 ON d1.div_id = d2.div_id
WHERE d2.player_id = 56
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9EPvPKfexJuMNnwNWcjNjh/0)

Comment: he only wants player, cell and email returned